# Riders on the storm fingering for piano

Tags: technique, piano, scales, fingering, keyboard

I'm talking about this little run:

[image]

I can't think of a proper fingering of this, so it sounds very **smooth**.
Its  basically in the Dmajor scale starting on b.

Can anyone help me getting the right fingering for this part?

---

PS: if you need to know what tempo it is in, and how it sounds, [listen to 0:25.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DKbPUzhWeeI)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

4-2-3-1 or 3-1-4-2 repeated should do it.  The second might be a little easier due to the placement of the sharps.

That's **if** you want to use only your right hand, though!  The left's not doing anything so you might as well take advantage of it.  Something like the below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this run is to think of it as the first 5 notes of two major chords; A and D. Start the run with your pinky on B, 3rd G, 4th A, 2nd F#, 3rd G, thumb E, 2nd F#, thumb D. You should then move your hand left and use the same fingering starting on E etc.
I hope you understand what I mean, there are numerous ways to play this run down but I think the above method is the best as it feels very controlled and minimizes the chance of making a mistake as the hand does not have to change position as frequently as other methods suggest.
All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Very true on the fingering pattern 5,3,4,2,3,1,2,1 shift right hand left and repeat downward.  Getting back to Hanon .

Comment: This is very unclear. What is "very true?" And by "getting back to Hanon" do you mean that _you_ have been looking over Hanon again, or that OP should be looking at Hanon, or something else? Please flesh your answer out a bit to improve its clarity and usefulness.

Answer (score 0):

Suggested Fender Rhodes RH fingering for
The Doors - Riders On The Storm,
bars 7 - 9 + the 1st inversion Em chord in bar 10

```
5 3 4 2 3 1 2 1
5 3 4 2 3 1 2 1
4 2 3 1 2 1
5 3 4 2 3 1 2 1
4 2 3 1 2 1
5 3 4 2 3 1 3
(1 3 5)(1 3 5)
```

[image: Suggested Fender Rhodes fingering for The Doors - Riders On The Storm bars 7 - 9 + the 1st inversion Em chord in bar 10]

Answer (score 0):

I do it by playing the first note of each descending third with the middle finger.  Then, if the second note is F# or C#, I play the second note with the index finger, otherwise I play it with my thumb.  I still need to look at my fingers on this one to see if the second note is a black key or white key, but my fingers are starting to do it by themselves.